# Updating a dbms record based on user input and existing dbms data(2)

Tags: php, database

[This is the page that uses this code.](http://www.davidsdomaindesign.com/marknutt/emails/all.php)I have a php page which extracts data from a dbms which contains email address. This works. It then displays the email address and other stored dbms data. The user then has the option of putting an "X" in a field designed in the php page called emailselected. This also works. I now want to update the dbms with the new field based on the stored email address but the update statement doesn't work. Please help. The code is listed here:

```
    include("db.php");
if (isset($_POST['ssubmit']))
    {
    $id_save = $test['id'];
    $emailselected_save = $_POST['emailselected'];
    $email_save = $test['email'];

    $rc = mysql_query("UPDATE emails SET selected='$emailselected_save' WHERE id = 'id'");
if (!$result) {
    die('What?: ' . mysql_error());
}
$num = mysql_affected_rows();
printf("Updated %d rows\n", $num);

    echo "<input type='button' value='Email(s) sent' onclick='goBack()' />";
mysql_close($conn);
    } else {echo "hello";}
?>
<form method='post'>
    <div id='headd'>
    <br />
    <input type='button' value='Close this window without Sending' onclick='goBack()' />
    <input type='submit' name='ssubmit' id='ssubmit' value='Send Email Now!!!' />
    <p>Place an "X" in the emails you wish to send!!!</p>
    </div>
        <br /><br/>

<?php
    include("db.php");  
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emails WHERE unsubscribe  != 'x' ORDER BY lastname ASC");
            while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
?>
    <table border='1' width='78%'>
    <tr align=\"left\">
        <td width='4%'><font color='black'><input type='text' size='1' id='emailselected' name='emailselected' /></font></td>
        <td width='15%'><font color='black'><?php echo $test['lastname']?></font></td>
        <td width='15%'><font color='black'><?php echo $test['firstname']?></font></td>
        <td width='40%'><font color='black'><?php echo $test['email']?></font></td>
        <td width='4%'><font color='black'><?php echo $test['id']?></font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
            }
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Do not use mysql_* as it is deprecated use mysqli_* or PDO instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is:

```
$rc = mysql_query("UPDATE emails SET selected='$emailselected_save' WHERE id = 'id'");
```

Should be:

```
$rc = mysql_query("UPDATE emails SET selected='$emailselected_save' WHERE id = '$id_save'");
```

**Your code is vulnerable for SQL injection.** So you should filter your data. But I would just switch to PDO and use prepared statements.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: it still doesn't work.  i have a message if its successful and one that printr either way.  they don't display either way.  this makes me think its not making it to the ssubmit statement.  any ideas

Comment: did you try to `var_dump()` To see you app flow, or you can use `xdebug` for same thing?

Comment: sorry but i am a slacker when it comes to some stuff.  var_dump() and xdebug are two of them.  can you explain in more detail.  thank you....david

Comment: on every step where your application changes path `if`, `else` add var_dump('unique label'); to see how your flow goes. If it goes correctly try to var_dump string tat is in your mysql_query to see if you run query you expect.